# App Name availability in different languages

Tags: iphone, ios

We are working on creating an iOS app and we are trying to reserve an app name on itunes connect. In itunes connect the first option to select is the default language and the problem we running into is if we trying to look for the app name with default language as "English", I get the error message that app name has already been used but if I change the default language option to "UK English" it doesn't give us that message anymore.

I am really confused because if the app name is already been used it should be for both English and UK English. I am not sure if I register my app name with UK English will i run into any problems later?

Thank you in advance.